# Build list from database objects based on certain properties

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, sqlite

This question is difficult to word, but here goes...

I'm working on a site to search for certain buildings. So i have "building" objects in my sqlite database with the following properties: State, City, County, Zip

When the user first arrives at the page, they will directed to select a state from a list. I want to be able to build this list based on my data. For instance, if i don't have an object in my database with a state property of Iowa, i don't want Iowa to be in the list.

I know i could get all of my data and roll through the state property on each one to check the state and create a list item for each new state, but i would prefer not to get all of my data like that unless it's the only way to do it.

Comment: since you are using asp.net mvc, I'm guessing you want a solution using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of those states that exist in the database, use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT State
FROM MyTable
```

To get a list of those cities in Iowa that exist in the database, use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM MyTable
WHERE State = ?
```

To make these queries efficient for all four levels, you need an index like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX whatever ON MyTable(State, City, Country, Zip);
```

Answer (score 1):

well my friend you have to check querys for sql, and in your function of searching give some queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT State FROM MyStateTable
```

this query will show all states differenced and non repeated

once you have this for the other sub query you have to do like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM MyCityTable WHERE State = (here goes your variable where you make your first sql transaction for states)
```

and then you compact all your information and show into your view, keep going sql queries are awesome .... :-D